# How to stack cards with position absolute?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

In advance, this question contains images, and I am unfamiliar with the best practices on how to post images. If my post is done poorly, I have no problem refactoring it.

I am trying to create a design for practice purposes. And I am having a bit of difficultly with positioning the cards. I believe using position absolute should create the desired effect and manually adjusting "top",but it's cutting off the top half of the card.

What I want to achieve is this:
[image]

What I have is:
[image]

The code I am using is:

```
 <Animated.View style={animatedStyles}>
          <View style={styles.phoneContainer}>
            <View style={{ position: "absolute" }}>
              <Deck deckColor="#ED29F9" />
              <View
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  bottom: 15
                }}
              >
                <Deck deckColor="red" />
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  bottom: 5,
                  left: 2
                }}
              >
                <Deck deckColor="#FFF5AB" />
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  position: "absolute"
                }}
              >
                <Deck deckColor="#78BDF0" />
              </View>
            </View>

          </View>
        </Animated.View>
```

Any help or clues will be greatly appreciated.

```
The component's code is:

const Deck = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.head} />
      <View style={styles.body}>
        <View style={styles.bodyContents}>
          <View style={styles.circle} />
          <View style={styles.text} />
          <View style={styles.text} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bodyContents: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    flex: 0.8,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    height: 30,
    borderRadius: 5,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: "#d2d2d2"
  },
  circle: {
    borderRadius: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#d2d2d2",
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    marginTop: 20
  },
  head: {
    backgroundColor: "#ED29F9",
    flex: 0.2,
    width: 250
  },
  body: {
    flex: 0.7,
    width: 250,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: "#d6d7da",
    backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a suggestion to you find the best way to do what you planning.

```
    // this code bellow I was testing in the App.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {View} from 'react-native';

    import Deck from './components/Deck';
    import ButtonReject from './components/ButtonReject';
    import ButtonAccept from './components/ButtonAccept';
    import TopBar from './components/Topbar';


    export default class App extends Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state={
            //array of decks
                decks: [
                    {
                        headColor: '#00FA9A',
                    },
                    {
                        headColor: '#8A2BE2',
                    },
                    {
                        headColor: '#1E90FF',
                    },
                    {
                        headColor: '#FFFF00'
                    },
                    {
                        headColor: '#FF6171'
                    }
                ],
            }
            // it's a Map that refer to the Decks Components in the container
            this.refDecks = new Map();
        }

        // Rejects a card
        reject(){
            // Calls the reject function in the last card in the deck 
            this.refDecks.get(this.state.decks.length-1).reject();
            this.removeCard();
        }

        // Accepts a card
        accept(){
            // Calls the accept function in the last card in the deck
            this.refDecks.get(this.state.decks.length-1).accept();
            // Calls the accept function in the topBar Component (it changes the heart color)
            this.topBar.accept();
            this.removeCard();

        }

        // Waits the time of the animation and remove the card
        removeCard(){
            setTimeout(()=>{
                decks = this.state.decks; 
                decks.splice(0, 1);
                this.setState({decks:decks});
            },250);
        }

        renderDeck(){
            // render the cards starting of the end (it changes the position props in the Decks, when a card is removed, so all others cards updates their positions in the deck)
            return this.state.decks.slice(0).reverse().map((deck,index) =>{
                return (
                     (this.refDecks.set(index, ref))} />
                )
            })
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <TopBar onRef = {ref =>{this.topBar = ref}} />
                    <View>
                        {this.renderDeck()}
                    </View>
                    <View style={{justifyContent:'flex-end'}}>
                        <ButtonReject reject={this.reject.bind(this)} />
                        <ButtonAccept accept={this.accept.bind(this)} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }



// fim do App.js

Component => ButtonReject.js



        import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import {
            StyleSheet,
            View,
            Text,
            TouchableOpacity,
            Dimensions
        } from 'react-native';

        export default class ButtonReject extends Component {
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
            }

            onPress() {
                this.props.reject();
            }

            render(){
                return (
                    <View style={styles.circle}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
                        >
                            <Text style={styles.textButton}> X 
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
               );
           }
       };

       const styles = StyleSheet.create({
           circle: {
              position: 'absolute',
              top: Dimensions.get('window').height - 150,
              left: Dimensions.get('window').width -280,
              borderRadius: 60,
              backgroundColor: "#888888",
              height: 60,
              width: 60,
              marginTop: 20,
              alignItems:'center',
              justifyContent: 'center'
          },
          textButton:{
              fontSize: 30,
              color: '#FFF'
          }
      });
      //fim do ButtonReject.js



Component => TopBar.js



import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      Dimensions
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class TopBar extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            heartColor:'#FFF'
        }
    }


    accept(){
        this.setState({heartColor:'#FF1493'});
        _this = this;
        setTimeout(()=>{
            _this.setState({heartColor:'#FFF'});
        },1000);
    }

    changeColor(color){
        this.setState({heartColor:color});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onRef(this)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.onRef(undefined)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.topBar}>
                <Icon name="md-heart" style={{left:Dimensions.get('window').width-50,top:20}} size={30} color={this.state.heartColor} />
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    topBar: {
        position: 'absolute',
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: 70,      
        backgroundColor: "#8A2BE2",
    },
    textButton:{
        fontSize: 30,
        color: '#FFF'
    }
});



Deck.js



    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        StyleSheet,
        View,
        Text,
        Animated,
        Dimensions,
        TouchableWithoutFeedback
    } from 'react-native';

    const animationDuration = 250;

    export default class Deck extends Component {

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state= {
                headColor:'',
                // show or hide the X to close the card, when the card is maximize
                maximized: false,
                left: new Animated.Value((Dimensions.get('window').width/2)-(150-(this.props.position*7.5))),
                top:  new Animated.Value((Dimensions.get('window').height/2)-140-(this.props.position*15)),
                height: new Animated.Value(300),
                width: new Animated.Value(300-(this.props.position*15))
            }
        }

        componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps){
            this.initialSize(nextProps);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.onRef(this)
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.props.onRef(undefined)
        }

        initialSize(props){
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(this.state.left, {
                    toValue: (Dimensions.get('window').width/2)-(150-(props.position*7.5)),
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.state.top, {
                    toValue: (Dimensions.get('window').height/2)-140-(props.position*15),
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
                    toValue: 300,
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
                    toValue: 300-(props.position*15),
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
            ]).start();
       }

       reject(){
           Animated.parallel([
               Animated.timing(this.state.top, {
                   toValue: Dimensions.get('window').height-20,
                   duration: animationDuration
               }),
               Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
                   toValue: 3,
                   duration: animationDuration
               }),
               Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
                   toValue: 300-(this.props.position*15)+50,
                   duration: animationDuration
               }),
           ]).start();
       }

       accept(){
            Animated.parallel([
                Animated.timing(this.state.left, {
                    toValue: Dimensions.get('window').width-50,
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.state.top, {
                    toValue: 20,
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
                    toValue: 20,
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
                    toValue: 20,
                    duration: animationDuration
                }),
            ]).start();
       }

       maximize(){
           if(this.props.position==1){
               Animated.parallel([
                   Animated.timing(this.state.left, {
                       toValue: 0,
                       duration: animationDuration
                   }),
                   Animated.timing(this.state.top, {
                       toValue: 0,
                       duration: animationDuration
                   }),
                   Animated.timing(this.state.height, {
                       toValue: Dimensions.get('window').height,
                       duration: animationDuration
                   }),
                   Animated.timing(this.state.width, {
                       toValue: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                       duration: animationDuration
                   }),
               ]).start();
               this.setState({maximized:true});
           }
       }

       minimize(){
           this.initialSize(this.props);
           this.setState({maximized:false});
       }


       render(){
           return (
               <Animated.View style={[styles.container,{top:this.state.top,left: this.state.left,height:this.state.height,width:this.state.width}]}>
                   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.maximize.bind(this)}>
                       <View style={[styles.head,{backgroundColor: this.props.headColor}]}>
                           {this.state.maximized && 
                           <View style={styles.containerCloseButton}>
                               <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.minimize.bind(this)}>
                                   <Text style={styles.closeButton}>X
                               </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                           </View>
                           }
                       </View>
                   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                   <View style={styles.body}>
                       <View style={styles.bodyContents}>
                           <View style={styles.circle} />
                           <View style={styles.text} />
                           <View style={styles.text} />
                       </View>
                   </View>
               </Animated.View>
           );
       }
   };

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       container: {
           position: "absolute",
       },
       bodyContents: {
           flexDirection: "column",
           flex: 0.8,
           justifyContent: "space-around",
           alignItems: "center"
       },
       text: {
           height: 30,
           borderRadius: 5,
           width: 100,
           backgroundColor: "#d2d2d2"
       },
       circle: {
           borderRadius: 50,
           backgroundColor: "#d2d2d2",
           height: 50,
           width: 50,
           marginTop: 20
       },
       head: {
           flex:1
       },
       body: {
           flex:4,
           borderRadius: 4,
           borderWidth: 0.5,
           borderColor: "#d6d7da",
           backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7"
       },
       containerCloseButton:{
           left: Dimensions.get('window').width-30,
           top: 20
       },
       closeButton:{
           fontSize: 30,
           color: '#FFF'
       }
   });
```

You can make yourself comfortable to ask me anything about the code.
Best Regards.

Comment: I posted the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I did make the changes for the styles. That did help a lot. I am still having trouble creating the distance between each card. I can visually show that there are several cards, but I cannot make it look beautiful like in the mockup. I edited my code to show what I am able to achieve. I am at a lost .

Comment: @o6t9o I did a animated interface such as you planned in the image above. Would you like that I send the code or would you prefer try yourself?

Comment: I would love it if you could send me the code. I have been at it for awhile now. I think I could really learn a lot from it.  If you could post it I can gladly accept your answer and give you credit.

Comment: @o6t9o The code is posted. I don't know if it's clarified, I had problems to format the code in the answer, but you make yourself comfortable to ask anytime.

Comment: Thank you so much for supplying the code. This is truly going way above what my initial question asked. I will later on go through each line of code. Thanks.